# How do I SELECT TOP X where it INCLUDES records based on a criteria?

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

I have a table, with multiple columns, including a column named "PolicyNumber"

Here's a sample:

```
PolicyNumber

NYH1111
NYD2222
SCH3333
SCS4444
LUH5555
LUS6666
ALH7777
ALW8888
VAH9999
AKH0000
...
NYH1010
NYD2318
```

There are 1,000+ records in this table and records contain several of each policy number types. For example, multiple policies starting with "NYH" or multiple policies starting with "VAH."

The possible policy types are here:

```
NYH
NYD
SCH
SCS
LUH
LUS
ALH
ALW
VAH
AKH
```

How do I do a SELECT TOP 300 where it'll INCLUDE at least one of each Policy Type? Remember, a policy type is the first 3 letters of a policy number.

Is this even possible? The purpose of this is that I have to grab 300 records from production to dump into a test environment and I need to include at least 1 of each policy. After I have at least one of each, it can be completely randomized.

Comment: Have you tried a `GROUP BY SUBSTRING(PolicyNumber, 1, 3)`?

Comment: group by wouldn't work in this case would it? It would throw all like policies to the top, thus removing the "random" selection

Comment: I'm sure what your asking for is possible, but as an alternative have you considered selecting say the TOP 50 for each type?  `WHERE PolicyID LIKE 'NYH%'` for each, then merge your results for the test bed.

Comment: @DJQuimby How about a `DISTINCT SUBSTRING(... ...ORDER BY RAND()`?

Comment: @DJQuimby, I guess I could do that and run multiple queries (1 for each policy type)... though 1 query for this would be nice!

Comment: @njk Depending on the number of records in the table, you wouldn't be able to guarantee that 1 of each type was present, though it's certainly closer

Comment: there are 44k records in the table btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

In this solution first there is the `newid()` with you can generate **random order by each running.**

To achive the "at least one from each policy" goal, I made the `AtLeastOne` column. This selects the first from the randomized `CTE` table for each unique three letters at the start. If the current `Policy` equals with this first selected value, then it gets 1 else 0. So with this logic, you can select a **randomized first one from each unique three letters.**

*Note: You can put this logic directly into the `Order By` part too if you need the Policy field only. (I made the example on this way to make the logic behind it visible)*

In the last step you just have to order by the `AtLeastOne Des`c and then by the random `ID`.

```
WITH CTE_Policy
AS
(
  SELECT newid() as  ID, Policy
  FROM Code
)
SELECT TOP 300
Policy,
CASE WHEN Policy = (SELECT TOP 1 Policy FROM cte_Policy c
                    WHERE SUBSTRING(c.Policy,1,3) = 
                      SUBSTRING(CTE_Policy.Policy,1,3))
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  AS AtLeastOne

FROM CTE_Policy
ORDER BY AtLeastOne DESC, ID
```

Here is an [SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7393/16).

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, you could do:

```
SELECT TOP 30 Column1, Column2, Column3, PolicyNumber
FROM YourTable
WHERE PolicyNumber LIKE 'NYH%'

UNION 

SELECT TOP 30 Column1, Column2, Column3, PolicyNumber
FROM YourTable
WHERE PolicyNumber LIKE 'NYD%'

UNION

/* ... remaining eight policy types go here */ 

ORDER BY PolicyNumber /* Or whatever sort order you want */
```

It will give you 30 of each type every time, instead of X of one type, and Y of another, however.

Answer (score 1):

one quick way that comes to my mind.. below query will grab just 1 record per policy type

```
 SELECT TOP 300 *

 FROM   ( SELECT *,rank1= ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT (PolicyNo,3) ORDER BY GETDATE ()) FROM MyTable
        ) AS t1

 WHERE  t1.rank1 = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for SQL Server 2005+:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  LEFT(PolicyNumber) PolicyType, PolicyNumber, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LEFT(PolicyNumber) ORDER BY NEWID()) RN
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT TOP 300 PolicyNumber
FROM CTE
ORDER BY RN, NEWID()
```

Answer (score 1):

Borrowed from ClearLogic +1  Please give the check to ClearLogic if this works

Problem with WHERE  t1.rank1 = 1 is that it will stop short of 300 if less then 300 unique

```
 SELECT TOP 300 t1.PolicyNo

 FROM   ( SELECT PolicyNo, rank1= ROW_NUMBER () 
          OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT (PolicyNo,3) ORDER BY NEWID()) 
          FROM MyTable
        ) AS t1

 order by t1.rank, t1.PolicyNo
```